# How get records by last date with specific query

Tags: php, mysql

I have table currencies and table this courses data . How i can get  one course data for each currency by last date
This is my code where i get courses for each currency by  date:

```
SELECT
    `coll_currency`.`collectionAlias`,
    `coll_currency`.`currency_abbr`,
    `coll_currency`.`currency_image`,
    `coll_currency`.`currency_name`,
    `coll_currency`.`currency_amount`,
    `coll_currency`.`id`,
    `pars_table`.`course` AS `currency_course`,
    `pars_table`.`publishdate` AS `currency_publishdate`,
    `pars_table`.`currency_id`
FROM
    `coll_currency`
INNER JOIN `pars_currency_nbu` AS `pars_table` 
   ON coll_currency.id = pars_table.currency_id
WHERE
    (
        (`currency_type` = '3670924')
        AND (`currency_state` = '3583429')
        AND (
            DATE_FORMAT(
                `pars_table`.`publishdate`,
                '%Y-%m-%d'
            ) = '2017-08-09'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    `currency_publishdate` DESC
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can use last update in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT `c`.`collectionAlias`,
       `c`.`currency_abbr`,
       `c`.`currency_image`,
       `c`.`currency_name`,
       `c`.`currency_amount`,
       `c`.`id`,
       `p`.`course` AS `currency_course`,
       `p`.`publishdate` AS `currency_publishdate`,
       `p`.`currency_id` -- this has the same value as `c`.`id`
FROM `coll_currency` AS `c`
JOIN `pars_currency_nbu` AS `p` ON `c`.`id` = `p`.`currency_id`
JOIN ( SELECT `cc`.`id`, MAX(`pp`.`publishdate`) AS `maxdate`
       FROM `coll_currency` AS `cc`
       JOIN `pars_currency_nbu` AS `pp` ON `cc`.`id` = `pp`.`currency_id`
       GROUP BY `cc`.`id`
     ) AS `q` ON `q`.id` = `c`.`id` AND `q`.`maxdate` = `p`.`publishdate`
```